# Similarity of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the symmetric matrix
$$G=
\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & -3 & 2 \\
-3 & 9 & -6 \\
2 & -6 & 4
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
and find, if they exist, a couple $(a,b)$ for which $G$ is similar to 
$$
H_{(a,b)}=
\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & b & a
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
Now: I'm a little bit rusty with linear algebra, so forgive if my question/conclusion is trivial.

However: I know that the trace is a similarity invariant, hence $a=14$. Then being the rank of a matrix an invariant too, being $\operatorname{rk}G=1$ it must be $\operatorname{rk}H_{(a,b)}=1$ which implies $b=0$.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: You should check characteristic polynomials are the same right? It never says it has to exist.

Comment: Characteristic polynomial is another invariant. I think the ones I choose are simpler to verify. Where is the problem?

Comment: @Joe, no need to check char. polynomial. With the two invariants you checked you already solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The two invariants are not sufficient for the similarity of $G$ and $H$. They are only necessary conditions to the similarity.

You must study the converse problem. Is there a basis $C=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ such that $$\left\{\begin{array}{l}Gu_1=0  \\Gu_2=0  \\ Gu_3=u_1+u_2+14u_3 \end{array} \right.$$

You have easily $u_1$ ans  $u_2$ since there are vectors of $\ker G$.

Comment: Yeah you're right. My answer was not complete! Thanks!